# UIWebView background image frame

Tags: ios, uiwebview

This is my code

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
        webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tripadvisorwaiting5.png"]];
        CGRect frame = webview.frame;
        frame.size.width = 320;
        frame.size.height = 568;
        webview.frame = frame;
    }
    else {
        webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tripadvisorwaiting.png"]];
        CGRect frame = webview.frame;
        frame.size.width = 320;
        frame.size.height = 480;
        webview.frame = frame;
    }
}
else {
    webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tripadvisorwaitingipad.png"]];
    CGRect frame = webview.frame;
    frame.size.width = 768;
    frame.size.height = 1024;
    webview.frame = frame;
}
```

but when the page loads, the image is too big or too small, and it's not scaled depending on the device.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `+colorWithPatternImage` sizes the image to the frame at the time you call it, so resizing the frame after calling `webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tripadvisorwaiting5.png"]];` would have no effect on scaling the image. Try setting the background image after you set the frame size. For instance:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    CGRect frame = webview.frame;
    frame.size.width = 320;
    frame.size.height = 568;
    webview.frame = frame;

    webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tripadvisorwaiting5.png"]];
}
```